# Обрезаются поля при выводе графика seaborn

Tags: seaborn

Прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой.
При выводе heatmap seaborn в jupyter notebook обрезаются верхняя и нижняя строки.

[image: Heatmap seaborn]

код взят из официальной документации, данные мои:
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 9))
sns.heatmap(resultsns, annot=True, fmt="d", ax=ax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оказывается, проблема в версии matplotlib. Ошибка на версии 3.1.1. Решается либо даунгрейдом до 3.0.3, либо необходимо подождать 3.1.2.
Нашел информацию тут https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773