# Почему в Jupyter Notebook обрезается часть графика?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Всем привет. Построил тепловую карту с помощью библиотеки seaborn.Часть визуальных данных по какой-то причине обрезалось. Как это исправить?
http://joxi.ru/zANqwgRt6nLa62

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обрезаются поля при выводе графика seaborn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036830/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-seaborn)